# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object - VF Page

Tags: visualforce, null-pointer

I am getting the mentioned error in the following line:

```
map1.get(PAPC.Country__c).Q1__c += (PAPC.Q1FX__c == null ? 0.0 : PAPC.Q1FX__c);
```

Baically it's assigning value from one object to the other.
`Q1FX__c`  can be zero at times .

Please help me understand why the error , since I'm encountering it for the first time.

Comment: Yes, but are you sure the value you want is in map1?

Comment: If any of these objects are null, you will get that error: `map1`, `map1.get(PAPC.Country__c)`, `PAPC`, `objPAPC`

Comment: Did you instantiate your map after diclaring?

Comment: @Jagular  Value will be getting assigned to field in map1

Answer (score 2):

Its because one of your object is null, try this

```
if(map1 != null && PAPC != null && map1.get(PAPC.Country__c) != null && PAPC != null && objPAPC != null)
{
    map1.get(PAPC.Country__c).Q1__c += (PAPC.Q1FX__c == null ? 0.0 : objPAPC.Q1FX__c); 
}
```

Comment: Your guard will still throw an NPE if `PAPC` is null because you are checking `PAPC.Country__c` before you check `PAPC`

Comment: Thats right @BarCotter, just edited code !!!

Comment: Any reason why it's working in other sandbox environments and not working in Production?

Comment: Is the data exactly the same in each environment?

Comment: May be you are initializing your objects if it finds any record. And there is no record as per condition in your code.

Comment: @Jagular  Yes data is exactly same in all environments .

Comment: @JitendraZaa There is data for the scenario I'm executing . And now it's not working for other scenarios which were working a couple of days back.